# O que testar/implementar em uma viewmodel?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, wpf, design-pattern

Estou tentando implementar um padrão MVVM (Model - View - Viewmodel) que é parente do MVP. 
Sendo que a ViewModel, pelo meu entendimento, é a responsável por "passar" os dados da camada View para a Model, fora a responsabilidade de fazer esse intermediação, o que mais implemento nela?
Por exemplo: Tenho uma regra onde no formulário de venda tenho um checkbox para Entrega (Sim/Não), e se este for marcado, habilitar ou mostrar os campos referente ao endereço, serem obrigatórios e sugerir nele o endereço do cliente informado que já está previamente cadastrado no repositório.
Onde implemento esse controle de habilitar/mostrar os campos e torná-los obrigatórios? E quanto a questão da sugestão do endereço?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sendo que a ViewModel, pelo meu entendimento, é a responsável por "passar" os dados da camada View para a Model, fora a responsabilidade de fazer esse intermediação, o que mais implemento nela?

A recíproca também é verdadeira: passar dados do *Model* para a *View*.

A principal função do *ViewModel* é representar parcialmente o *Model* para não expôr este último. Como pode ser perigoso expôr uma entidade de *Model* diretamente, usa-se *ViewModels* para sanear a entrada e saída de dados, além de implementar lógicas de validação específicas.

> Por exemplo: Tenho uma regra onde no formulário de venda tenho um checkbox para Entrega (Sim/Não), e se este for marcado, habilitar ou mostrar os campos referente ao endereço, serem obrigatórios e sugerir nele o endereço do cliente informado que já está previamente cadastrado no repositório.

A validação de campos (campo obrigatório, limite de caracteres, etc.) são sim enunciadas por um *ViewModel*. Os demais comportamentos visuais (habilitação de campos, sugestão de endereços) são funcionalidades que fazem parte da camada de apresentação, por serem eventos que lidam com aspectos visuais e comportamento de campos na tela.

> Onde implemento esse controle de habilitar/mostrar os campos e torná-los obrigatórios? E quanto a questão da sugestão do endereço?

Em resumo:

- Habilitar/mostrar os campos: *View*;
- Sugestão de endereço: *View*;
- Obrigatoridade de preenchimento de acordo com demais campos da tela: *ViewModel* (veja também o [`IValidatableObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Em alguns casos não seria mais viável expor o model através de binds e colocar as regras de validação neles? No meu ponto de vista, muitas validações também fazem parte das regras do negócio.

Comment: Esta é a forma padrão, aliás. Eu uso assim por definição. Só quando preciso de algum comportamento mais específico uso *ViewModels*.